# Install Phalcon 3.4.3 and getting 4.0 Alpha

Tags: php, phalcon

If run the usual download and, then run install, what I get reports '4.0.0-alpha.3' as the version.

How do I get version 3.4.3?  I am updating a production server so the alpha version is a non-starter.

Commands I Executed:

```
git clone --depth=1 "git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git"
cd cphalcon/build
sudo ./install
```

The following is what phpinfo displays:

```
phalcon
Web framework delivered as a C-extension for PHP
phalcon => enabled
Author => Phalcon Team and contributors
Version => 4.0.0-alpha.3
Build Date => May  1 2019 16:04:36
Powered by Zephir => Version 0.11.11-b661a58
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build the 3.4.3 branch instead of the master branch, which is currently at version 4.0.x.  You can either download the code for 3.4.3, or, if you want to continue to use git, you can checkout the 3.4.x branch after you clone the repo.  The 3.4.x branch is currently on version 3.4.3.

```
git clone https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon
cd cphalcon/build
git checkout origin/3.4.x
sudo ./install
```

Comment: It is possible to clone a specific single branch with git in one step.

`git clone --single-branch --branch 3.4.x https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git /tmp/cphalcon`  

`cd /tmp/cphalcon/build`  

`sudo ./install`

Answer (score 5):

I was having trouble building, but I found that you can also install a previous version if it's still included in the installer cache.

e.g. Ubunutu Bionic install for PHP7.2 using `apt-get`

After adding the repository step:

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get update
```

You can check the cache with: `apt-cache policy php7.2-phalcon`

```
php7.2-phalcon:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.5-923+php7.2
  Version table:
     4.0.5-923+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.4-908+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.3-894+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.2-884+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.0-861+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.0-860+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.4.5-1+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.4.4-1+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.4.3-1+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.4.2-7+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.4.2-6+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.4.2-5+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.4.2-4+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.4.2-3+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.4.2-2+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.4.2-1+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.4.1-1+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     3.4.0-5+php7.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

You can then install a specific version by appending the version:
`sudo apt-get install php7.2-phalcon=3.4.3-1+php7.2`

Comment: sudo apt-get install php7.2-phalcon=3.4.3-1+php7.2
Este comando resolveu meu caso rapidamente! Muito obrigado